# UWP Adjust Control layout/position based on Screen Size

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have created a very crude user interface currently that contains a NavigationView and an ItemsControl that displays information from a UserData class.

Im looking into ways of implementing a dynamic interface that resizes the Frame Content based on the windows size. Ive currently got the Navigation view set to Minimal permanently as a design choice and added a Frame containing the ItemsControl. When I execute the program in non maximised mode, the screen looks like the following:

[image]

When i maximise the page, the Control shows up as intended:

[image]

I believe its something to do with the margin I have set but I'm not sure how best to implement the dynamic movement of the control. I believe Navigation view has all of this prebaked into it which is why it moves with the window size. I would like to do something similar so the control follows when re-sizing.
What would usually be the best way of doing this. Ive seen VisualStateTriggers mentioned a few times and was wondering if this is best practice to try to implement. I feel as though it is the Frame that i need to be re-sizing rather than the ItemsControl as well. Is this the case?

I would still like to keep the 40 pixel margin spacing around each edge (except if the bottom) to keep the visuals in check.

For those that need it, here is the current XAML for the overall design/Layout:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BudgetSheet.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:mux="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls"    

    xmlns:data="using:BudgetSheet.Data"   

    RequestedTheme="Dark">

    <Page.Resources>
        <data:UserDataCollection x:Key="userDataCollection"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Frame Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">

        <!-- Navigation view Variable decleration -->
        <mux:NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="False" 
                            PaneTitle=" Budget Sheet Menu "                            
                            x:Name="NavView"                             
                            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" 
                            PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal" 
                            AlwaysShowHeader="True"        
                            SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged">

            <!-- All navigation view Items nested within here -->
            <mux:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Page2" Margin="0, 2, 1, 0" Tag="New_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="NewFile_ClickAsync"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Open_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="OpenFile_ClickAsync"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Save_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SaveButton_ClickAsync"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Calculator" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Calculator_Open" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="CalcButton_ClickAsync"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <mux:NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="HomeItem" 
                                        Content="HOME" 
                                        Tag="HOME_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="OverviewItem" 
                                        Content="ACCOUNT OVERVIEW" 
                                        Tag="OverView_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="BillsItem" 
                                        Content="BILLS" 
                                        Tag="Bills_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="PeopleItem" 
                                        Content="BILL PAYERS" 
                                        Tag="BillPayer_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="TransfersItem" 
                                        Content="BANK TRANSFERS" 
                                        Tag="Transfers_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>

                <mux:NavigationViewItem Name="PayDatesItem" 
                                        Content="PAY DATES" 
                                        Tag="PayDates_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="#b880fc"/>
            </mux:NavigationView.MenuItems>


            <!-- Defining the ContentFrame Transition effect-->
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1920" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Frame.ContentTransitions>


                <!-- All information display is in here. This displays the "Accounts at a Glance" control-->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource userDataCollection}" Margin="40,40,40,727">

                    <!-- Changing Orientation of VirtualizingStackPanel -->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <!-- Change header for ItemsControl -->
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Accounts At A Glance" FontSize="28" Foreground="#b880fc" Padding="12"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>


                    <!-- Design template for each card-->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="240" Height="240" Background="Gray" Margin="30,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="4">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="24"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PayDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <!-- End of Frame Display-->
            </Frame>



            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <Button x:Name="ChangeUser" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Foreground="#b880fc" >
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Contact" Margin="8"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">      
                                    Change User
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        </mux:NavigationView>


    </Frame>
</Page>
```

I apologise for any inconvenience with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all you should not set the **width of the Frame**, remove the width property and you dont need to set HorizontalAlignment or VerticalAlignment of Frame as well, because frame automatically stretches itself to the available space.
>
> the second mistake you are making is to set wild margins to the **ItemsControl** your lower margin is just too high. remove the margins and if you want some margin just set **Margin="12"** ( this will set 12 margin on all 4 sides ).
>
> Mistake number 3 is setting the **Margin="30,0,0,0"** to the Grid within your **DataTemplate** keep the margin uniform on all 3 sides, maybe set **Margin="8"** here.
>
> Last of all I dont know why you are using ItemsControl when you can simply use a **GridView** which is much straight forward and simpler to use?

Here is the fixed and refined simpler code below to do what you are trying to achieve :

```
<!-- Defining the ContentFrame Transition effect-->
<Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
    <Frame.ContentTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Frame.ContentTransitions>


    <!-- All information display is in here. This displays the "Accounts at a Glance" control-->
    <GridView ItemsSource="{StaticResource userDataCollection}" Margin="12"
              Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">
        <GridView.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Accounts At A Glance" FontSize="28" Foreground="#b880fc" Padding="12"/>
        </GridView.Header>

        <!-- Design template for each card-->
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="240" Height="240" Background="Gray" Margin="12" Padding="4">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <!--you dont need this 4th row below because you have only 3 textblocks and this 4th row with * is causing your content to be pushed upwards within a gridviewitem.-->
                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="*"/>-->
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="24"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PayDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <!-- End of Frame Display-->
</Frame>
```

Comment: Many thanks! I will apply all of this. I was advised to use ItemsControl in another post as apparently GridView would not perform the required task. I guess that was wrong and thank you for the guidance on this. Youve been a great help and its appreciated :)

Comment: always happy to help :)